# Is this input sanitization regex safe?

Tags: javascript, regex, input, sanitization

I have an input field where I expect the user to enter the name of a place (city/town/village/whatever). I have this function which is use to sanitize the content of the input field.

```
sanitizeInput: function (input) {
        return input.replaceAll(/[&/\\#,+()$~%.^'":*?<>{}]/g, "");
    }
```

I want to remove all special characters that I expect not to appear in place name. I thought a blacklist regex is better than a whitelist regex because there are still many characters that might appear in a place name.

My questions are:

1. Is this regex safe?
2. Could it be improved?
3. Do you see a way to attack the program using this regex?

**EDIT: This is a tiny frontend-only project. There is no backend.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is perfect to remove any special characters.
The answers are :

1.the regex is safe , but as you mentioned it is a vuejs project so the js function will run on browser. Browsers basically not safe for doing user input sanitization. You should do that in backend server also , to be 100% safe

2. You can not improve the regex itself in this example. But instead of regex , you could use indexOf for each special characters also ( it will be fastest process but more verbose and too much code)
   Like :
   str.indexOf('&') !== -1
   str.indexOf('#') !== -1
   Etc

3.same as answer 1,the regex is safe but as it is used in browser js , the code an be disabled , so please do server side validation also.

If you have any issue with this answer ,please let me know by comment or reply.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to remember that front end sanitization is mainly to improve the user experience and protect against accidental data input errors. There are ways to get past front end controls. For this reason, it is important to rely on sanitizing data on the backend for security purposes. This may not be the answer to your question, but based on what you are using for a backend, you may need to sanitize certain things or it may have built in controls and you may not need to worry about further sanitization.

ps.
Please forgive my lack of references. But it is worth researching on your own.

Comment: Well, my project does not have a backend of my own. This is a very small frontend only project.

Comment: Then I would agree with subhadip pahari. If you are just worried about a scripting attack, I would say you have adequately protected yourself against it! Heres a tool I have found helpful for testing regex in the past: https://regex101.com/